# When an Activity instance is destroyed during a configuration change, are the Loaders associated with it also destroyed?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

From this developer guide on Loaders,

> They automatically reconnect to the ***last loader's cursor*** when being
>   recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to
>   re-query their data.

I assume that by "last loader", they mean that the loader which was destroyed when the Activity was destroyed during the configuration change. Then by saying "last loader's cursor", they mean the cursor which was associated with the last loader. This tells us that **when an Activity is destroyed because of a configuration change, its loaders are also destroyed, but the cursors (or any other form of data that the loader has loaded) is not destroyed.  Is that correct?**

Actually it is a little difficult to internalize this. My intuition says that when the loader is destroyed, everything associated with it, including the cursor associated with it should also be destroyed.

Comment: yes, loader are too.

Comment: @Androider Loaders are too what?

Comment: check it http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html and google,

Comment: yes, loader are too dee too

Comment: @pskink I think you mean Loaders are destroyed when the Activity is destroyed during a configuration change. Thank you. But what about the data the Loader has loaded, e.g. a cursor. Will it remain alive?

Comment: @Androider Thanks, I have read this guide a few times, and a few blogs as well,  and at this point I can use Loaders in a my app, and probably can write a custom loader as well, but I am still not clear about this point about a loader's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Loader` instance is kept alive during configuration change. The `LoaderCallbacks` of the old Activity is disconnected and the new one reconnected.

Take a look at [`LoaderManager.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java) around the `retain()` and `finishRetain()` methods of `LoaderInfo`. You can see that the `mCallbacks` field is nulled, but the `mLoader` field is not.

The initialization of these fields happens in `LoaderInfo.start()`, where you can see that `mCallbacks.onCreateLoader()` is **only** invoked if `mLoader` is null.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your answer. Now being honest, I have never read code of an Android's builtin class, and this one is not even commented. I can't find out what `LoaderInfo` represents, what `retain()` and `finishRetain()` do. Have you read the entire code of the class and connected bits and pieces in your mind to understand the entire functioning?

Comment: "The Loader instance is kept alive during configuration change. " - but why do they say " **old** loader" in the statement I have quoted from the developer guide? And secondly this means that a Loader instance is like Never destroyed (because when else would it ever be destroyed)? When would a Loader instance ever be destroyed, and when would it ever be stopped?

Comment: I know this stuff from having used it in a huge app for the past three years. The loader API is weird, and even after all this time I cannot say I can write a loader from scratch. I honestly wouldn't use the API in a new project. You can see why alternatives such as EventBus are so popular! To answer your comment, the `LoaderInfo` objects are what `LoaderManager` uses to keep track of all the loaders it manages; there's one `LoaderInfo` for each loader. A loader is destroyed after you call `LoaderManager.destroyLoader(int)`, which you should do in the `onDestroy()` callback of your activity.